# How to mock environment variables and packages before importing Python script using pytest tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am using `pytest` to test out an AWS Lambda function I am writing. The function has some initialization code outside of any function. It looks similar to this:

catalog_service/lambda_v1.py

```py
import boto3
import botocore
import json
import os

from aws_lambda_powertools import Logger
from elastic_enterprise_search import AppSearch


LOGGER = Logger()
ENV = os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
key_response = ssm.get_parameter(
    Name=key,
    WithDecryption=True
    )
APP_SEARCH = AppSearch(
    os.environ['APP_SEARCH_API_HOST'],
    bearer_auth=key_response['Parameter']['Value'],
    )

# Additional functions
```

Whenever I run my test, it always fails with a `KeyError` saying that `ENVIRONMENT` is not in `os.environ` which makes sense since I believe it's importing the Lambda script before running any of the other mocking code. Whenever I try to mock it with `monkeypatch` it seems like I am not doing it in the right spot. My test looks like this:

```py
import pytest
import os
from . import fixtures
from catalog_service import lambda_v1 as v1

@pytest.fixture
def mock_set_environment(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('ENVIRONMENT', 'qa')

class TestLambdaV1:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('data, expected', [
        (
            {'a': 1},
            {
                'statusCode': '200',
                'headers': {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                'body': '{"a": 1}'
                },
            ),
        ])
    def test_format_good_response(self, mock_set_environment, data, expected):
        assert os.getenv('ENVIRONMENT') == 'qa'
        result = v1.format_good_response(data)
        assert result == expected
```

I think it would mock the environment variable if it were being used within the function but it is used during the `import`. How do I mock the `os.environ` variable as well as the `AppSearch` and `boto3` packages before they're imported / used?

Comment: you need to import _after_ you mock _or_ reload the module after the mock